# Placing the final close vote on a question in Review resets the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, review

On the Review page of SO, when you cast the final close vote for a question, regardless of where you are on the page, it scrolls down to the bottom and resets the page with 30 new questions to review.

Not a major problem, but it is slightly annoying to get whisked away from the workflow.

Comment: Chrome 15, in case this could be browser specific.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't seen that behavior, but I _have_ been whisked away from /Review to the actual page of the question I just cast the 5th close vote on. Also in Chrome 15. I've held off asking about it because I can't reproduce it reliably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed, the close workflow in review is **MUCH** improved ...

We now collapse it to a single line after your close vote.